# How to format a cell based on another cells value using rhandsontable

Tags: rhandsontable

I am new to rhandsontable package and i am trying to highlight a cell based on value in another cell.I want to highlight values in column 'gear' in mtcars data set when mpg==21.I  don't have any clue how to do.Appreciate some help in rhandsontable

```
rhandsontable(mtcars, readOnly = TRUE, width = 750, height = 
300)%>%hot_cols(renderer = "
             function (instance, td, row, col       , prop, value, 
cellProperties) {
             Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
var col_value = instance.getData()[XXXXXXXXXXX][XXXXXXXXX]
             if (col_value ==21) {
             td.style.background = 'pink';
             }else if (col_value !=21) {
  td.style.background = 'green';
  }
             }")
```

I am not sure how to write above code to achieve my result

Answer (score 2):

The following code gets the job done:

```
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput('hot')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(mtcars, readOnly = TRUE, width = 750, height = 300) %>%
    hot_cols(renderer = myrenderer)
  })

  myrenderer <- "function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {

  Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

  if (col == 9 && instance.getData()[row][0] == 21 ) {  
    td.style.background = 'pink';
  }
  }"
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: How to check for max value in a column or a value in a particular cell to validate?